# How to extract column values from from nested JSON in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am working on a PySpark dataframe(`es_query`) which contains nested JSON columns(`r_json`, `brd_json`, `vs_json`). I need assistance in extracting the column data and storing it in another dataframe(`e_result`) as two different columns for the values of URL and product number where each is an individual record in each row.

In the end, we have to put all the values into one dataframe.

The sample data for the individual columns mentioned above are as below:

```json
r_json:
results:
0: {"col1": "Yes", "name": "", "col2":  1, "col3": "76,67 €", "col4": "5,75 €", "productNumber": "B0e28213", "url": "https://www.am"}
1: {"col1": "Yes", "name": "", "col2":  1, "col3": "76,67 €", "col4": "5,75 €", "productNumber": "019883", "url": "https://www.am"}

brd_json:
array:
0: {"col1": "Yes", "col2": "https://m.media-a", "col3": null, "col4": "Yes", , "col5": "No", "col6": false, "productNumber": "11873628", "rating": "4.1", "url": "https://www.amazon"}
1: {"col1": "Yes", "col2": "https://m.media-a", "col3": null, "col4": "Yes", , "col5": "No", "col6": false, "productNumber": "001838", "rating": "4.1", "url": "https://www.amazon"}

vs_json:
array:
0: 0: {"col1": "Yes", "col2": "https://m.media-a", "col3": null, "col4": "Yes", , "col5": "No", "col6": false, "productNumber": "1212", "rating": "4.1", "url": "https://www.amazon"}
1: 0: {"col1": "Yes", "col2": "https://m.media-a", "col3": null, "col4": "Yes", , "col5": "No", "col6": false, "productNumber": "2321", "rating": "4.1", "url": "https://www.amazon"}
```

Can I get some help in writing the script? Below is what I tried:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

result_urls = results.select("url").withColumn("source", lit("result"))
brsd_json_url = brsd_json.select("url").withColumn("source", lit("brand"))
vis_json_url = brsd_json.select("url").withColumn("source", lit("video"))

combined_urls = result_urls.union(brsd_json_url).union(vis_json_url)

esearch_result = combined_urls.groupBy("source").agg({"url": "concat_ws"}).select("concat_ws(url) as prod_page_url_address")
```

i tried the below which is able to help extract all the column as separate pyspark dataframe but the situation is how to combine them into one dataframe considering all the values

```
column_names = ["url", "productNumber", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", 
                "col6", "col7"]

# Define a function to create the expressions
def create_expr(column_name, json_column):
    try:
        expr = esearch_request_query.selectExpr(f"EXPLODE({json_column}.{column_name}) as {column_name}")
    except:
        expr = None
    return expr

# Iterate over the column names
for column_name in column_names:
    results_expr = create_expr(column_name, "result_json.re")
    brsd_json_url  = create_expr(column_name, "brsd_json")
    vis_json_url  = create_expr(column_name, "vis_json")

    globals()[f"results_{column_name}"] = results_expr
    globals()[f"brsd_json_{column_name}"] = brsd_json_url
    globals()[f"vis_json_{column_name}"] = vis_json_url

# case where "col2" does not exist in sponsored_video_json
try:
    results_brandName = esearch_request_query.selectExpr("EXPLODE(result_json.re.col2) as col2_name")
except:
    results_brandName = None

try:
    sponnd_col2 = esearch_request_query.selectExpr("EXPLODE(brsd_json.spon) as col2_name")
except:
    spond_col2 = None

spovideo_col2 = None  # Handle this case separately, as it does not exist in vis_json
```

Comment: Could you include some more detailed code? How do you get your data to the script?

Comment: i generally read the data from a storage account 
webscrap_load_df = spark.read.format("json").load(f"abfss://{container_name}@{storageAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1/*/*")
and i then use the to prepare the dataframe (es_query)

Comment: Ok, can you add that code to the script you have in your question? You're referencing a `results` variable that does not exist in your code snippet.

Comment: Could you add the `results` variable in your code snippet?

Comment: i am using the second code which is creating individual dataframes. i wish to figure out a way as how to combine all the dataframes into one and have a cumulative dataframe

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Also you can add complete input json for better understand ?

Comment: @batman_special Give us sample input and output

Comment: |-- result_json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Brand: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Video: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1 string (nullable = true)
thats the sample schema

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you want to extract the column data and store it in another dataframe (e_result). I have defined the schema and tried the following approach:

```
es_query = spark.createDataFrame([data], schema=schema)
r_json_df = es_query.select(explode("r_json").alias("r_json")).select(
    col("r_json.productNumber").alias("productNumber"),
    col("r_json.url").alias("url")
)
brd_json_df = es_query.select(explode("brd_json").alias("brd_json")).select(
    col("brd_json.productNumber").alias("productNumber"),
    col("brd_json.url").alias("url")
)
vs_json_df = es_query.select(explode("vs_json").alias("vs_json")).select(
    col("vs_json.productNumber").alias("productNumber"),
    col("vs_json.url").alias("url")
)
e_result = r_json_df.union(brd_json_df).union(vs_json_df)
e_result.show(truncate=False)
```

Results:

```
+-------------+------------------+
|productNumber|url               |
+-------------+------------------+
|B0e28213     |https://www.am    |
|019883       |https://www.am    |
|11873628     |https://www.amazon|
|001838       |https://www.amazon|
|1212         |https://www.amazon|
|2321         |https://www.amazon|
+-------------+------------------+
```

- In the above code, it selects the r_json array column from es_query, explodes it to separate each element into a new row, and then selects the productNumber and url fields from the exploded r_json column.
- Next, it extracts productNumber and url from the brd_json array column.
- Then, it extracts productNumber and url from the vs_json array column. Finally, it combines the DataFrames r_json_df, brd_json_df, and vs_json_df into a single DataFrame e_result by using union.